# Self-service options in Amsterdam

Tags: europe, accommodation, rental, amsterdam, netherlands

I'm considering a trip to Amsterdam with some friends (3-4 people) for around a week in the late spring/summer. Looking at hotel prices seems a little bit steep, and I've had success in the past in Europe with self-service apartments. The idea would be to save some money buying and cooking food ourselves while still having comfortable living accommodations. Preferably I'd like somewhere that costs less than a comparable hotel room would. Are there options for a self service-style apartment/flat in the Amsterdam area? What should I look for specifically and where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amsterdam, like all big cities, is expensive. Any rental apartments will be rented out to expat workers quickly, you're unlikely to find any (and they tend to be bloody expensive).

Your best bet is to find a hotel in another city and commute in by train. Leiden, Almere, maybe Amersfoort of Hilversum are all not far from Amsterdam. Leiden is a nice old city in its own right, very old university town with a rich history and lots of things to do and see, and should be cheaper than Amsterdam even considering the cost of train tickets.

Any vacation apartments in the Netherlands tend to be blocked together in self contained resort like complexes well away from major cities. There's a few on the coast, but without a car you're not going to want to stay there (plus rentals there can be more costly than a hotel room).

Comment: (-1) That's not true, you can definitely find self-catered houses or apartments to rent for a short time in and around cities in the Netherlands, I have done it several times for visitors (although never in Amsterdam itself as I live elsewhere). Like everywhere else, it's a completely different market than long-term rentals or Center Parcs-like resorts and it's going to cost more than a long-term rental but it can still be cheaper than a hotel for a group.

Comment: Also -1, only because i cant give -2. First of all check airbnb or only appartment and you'll see several options in Amsterdam. Furthermore places like Hilversum and leiden aren't cheaper by default.

Answer (score 6):

There is a local website called [Stay Amsterdam](http://www.stayamsterdam.com/).

You can also take a look at [Roomorama](https://roomorama.com/short-term-rentals?utf8=%E2%9C%93&destination=amsterdam&check_in=&check_out=&guests=1&commit=Find%20Now) or [AirBnb](http://www.airbnb.com/search).

Answer (score 1):

I used a site called [Citymundo](http://amsterdam.citymundo.com/) several years back - they are notable for having houseboat rentals in addition to the usual apartments. Both are rentals-by-owner, they act somewhat as an agent; you have to arrange to meet up with the owner in person when you arrive to pay and get the keys.

Comment: Citymundo appears to be defunct and the site is occupied by a domain squatter.

Comment: @RobertAtkins - are you sure? I just checked out http://amsterdam.citymundo.com, and it appears to be current - the reviews page has recently added items. The company is also listed on the official Amsterdam Tourism site, http://www.iamsterdam.com/en/placestogo/amsterdam-citymundo/ec248d76-097c-4d57-9de9-121c7917ad22